# Merge multiple folders and subfolders with differing names in macOS

Tags: macos, automator, folders, automation

I have multiple folders and subfolders that I need to merge. Merging them manually would take ages (300+ folders). I can't figure out how to use ditto correctly to solve my problem. I do not know if ditto can provide me with an appropriate solution.

The parent folders are named B1, B2, B3, ... and C1, C2, C3, ... going through all the letters of the alphabet until F1, F2, F3, ...

I would need to merge all the folders with letter B into one B-parent folder, conserving the structure for the subfolders. The same should be done for all the other parent-folders.

Some subfolders exist in both parent folders and sometimes files in each subfolder and sub-subfolders  are the same.

E.g.

```
FOLDER B1 | FOLDER B2 |  FOLDER B3 | ... | FOLDER B38 || FOLDER C1 |  FOLDER C2 | ... |  FOLDER C22 | ... 
----------------------- 

SUB 1     | SUB 1     |     1      | ... |     1      ||     1     |     1      | ...           

SUB 2     | SUB 2     |     2      | ... |     2      ||     2     |     2      | ...     

SUB 3     | SUB 3     |    ...     | ... |    ...     ||     3     |     3      | ...           

    ...   |  ...
```

should merge to

```
FOLDER B | FOLDER C |  FOLDER D | ... | FOLDER F |  
----------------------- 

SUB 1     | SUB 1   |     1     | ... |     1    |         

SUB 2     | SUB 2   |     2     | ... |     2    |   

SUB 3     | SUB 3   |    ...    | ... |    ...   |
```

I'm operating on Catalina 10.15.

Comment: Do all the subfolders have different names within a "B"s?  What happens when subfolders names conflict.?

Comment: Subfolders have in some cases the same name. This also goes for files which are located in those folders. They should be merged. All parent folders are named differently. Folder names are "[letter (A-F)]+[space]+[increasing number (2-328)]"

Comment: Providing you have adequate disk space to preform the necessary operations, I'd probably consider using: `rsync`

Comment: Check out this thread. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194144/osx-how-to-compare-and-merge-two-folders-and-their-subfolders-and-differing-fil?rq=1